# multiple panels sharing a bindingsource

Tags: winforms, binding, controls

My C# winforms project has 2 controls that I made.

PersonFormControl and PersonListControl

I have placed these controls on a form called PersonForm
There is also a bindingSource on the form.

How do I bind both PersonFormControl and PersonListControl to the same bindingSource?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to work around my issue by making the bindingsource.Datasource properties all point to the same object